# Como alterar o nome default das colunas da tabela users do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho interesse em alterar o nome default das colunas da tabela **users** e **password_reset** do Laravel 5.3.

Minha dúvida é, em quais locais ou arquivos de configuração devo replicar essa alteração?

Comment: Qual o motivo, pergunto porque esse campo por exemplo é usado para recuperar a senha e existe o algoritmo pronto?

Comment: A ideia seria sobrescrever os campos na tabela para que sigam todas o padrão pt-br. Consigo mapear isso na aplicação, ou seja, dá um alias ou algo do tipo para que no banco seja um nome mas a aplicação ainda consiga lidar com processo de login, recuperação de senha etc.

Comment: Particularmente eu não indicaria o `password_reset` por exemplo tem que alterar código nativo do `core` não acho legal já visto que qualquer atualização você perderia isso, Você pode até colocar mais campos mais esses que são `email, password  e password_reset` eu não colocaria a mão, eles não tem configuração para alterar o nome talvez em outras versões... !

Comment: Entendi, então melhor não alterar isso né

Comment: Não, pode acrescentar campos isso pode, alterar esses pode dar problemas